# Enable application to send emails in Exchange 365 hybrid deployment

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

Question from a still-learning Exchange administrator:

Is there a recommended way to create & configure an email account to be used solely by an application to send messages (alerts, reports, etc.) in an Exchange 365 hybrid deployment? The email address should not be able to receive messages.

I know I can create a dedicated Active Directory user and link that user to an Exchange 365 hosted mailbox. But that requires unique attention to the AD permissions and mail flow rules. It also consumes an Office 365 license (there could be a lot of these).

This must be a very common requirement. Is there an easy to manage, straightforward way of doing this?

p.s. I have a SMTP relay that accepts and forwards emails without authentication, but that only works for applications that are located behind the same firewall as the relay. I'm looking for solutions that will work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send to Exchange (Online or otherwise) without needing a mailbox, Exchange Web Services will be your best friend.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx

You will not need a full licensed mailbox to leverage EWS, however there are restrictions.  Learn more about those here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066(v=exchg.150).aspx

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchangewebservices) will have finer pointed questions and answers than Server Fault.  Try looking there and asking/refining a question.